# htaccess: mod_expires.c except one or multiple folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache, mod-expires

To the following *browser caching* via `mod_expires.c` in the `.htaccess`...

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
</IfModule>
```

...I would like to add an exception: **One or more folders shall not be cached.** I tried a version with `Directory` before `</IfModule>`, but that led to a 500 Internal Server Error. That

```
<Directory "/absolute/path/to/specialfolder">
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
</Directory>
```

and that snippet

```
<Directory "/absolute/path/to/specialfolder">
ExpiresActive Off
</Directory>
```

What's wrong and what could help? (for one or a few folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Directory>` directive is not permitted in a `.htaccess` context, it can only be used in a server (or virtualhost) context. (Hence the 500 error.)

The userland/`.htaccess` way would be to create another `.htaccess` file in that "specialfolder" with `ExpiresActive Off` in order to override the parent config.

Alternatively, you could perhaps use an `<If>` expression in the root `.htaccess` file.

For example:

```
# Turn off mod_expires for a specific directory
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/specialfolder/#"> 
    ExpiresActive Off
</If>
```

Where `REQUEST_URI` is the document-root-relative URL-path.

OR, only use mod_expires when *not* requesting these folder(s). For example:

```
# Only use mod_expires when NOT requesting the specific directories
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/(specialfolder|anotherfolder)/#"> 
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
</IfModule>
```

> One or more folders shall not be cached.

Although disabling mod_expires does not necessarily prevent the resource from being cached. It simply prevents mod_expires from setting the `Cache-Control` (and `Expires`) headers. If you specifically want to disable caching then consider explicitly setting the relevant `Cache-Control`/`Expires` header(s) directly.

For example:

```
# Set env var when special "none-cache" folder requested:
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(specialfolder|anotherfolder)/" NOCACHE

# Set no-cache headers if NOCACHE env var is set
Header always set Cache-Control "no-store" env=NOCACHE
Header always set Expires "0" env=NOCACHE
```

In this example, you do not need to disable mod_expires since the `Header` directive will override mod_expires (since mod_headers is processed *after* mod_expires).